# CRM Dynamics 2013 Website in IFrame not responding

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have written a webpage in ASP.net that has input fields and a upload control, I upload and submit the file to a server and add to database. I have hosted this website in IIS, and now I have added the website into CRM in an IFrame, however it does not function, I click on the submit button and nothing happens, I tested the website outside of CRM and all works fine, any idea what might be causing this issue. Pleas assist, this is for MS CRM 2013 on Premisis

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code is hard to know but it might be a cross domain issue? Do you see any security errors in the Developer console (F12)?